# Which right grants user a right to grant another right to himself in SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

I need to grant a `db_datawriter` before executing `SqlBulkCopy` and remove it after:

```
try
{
   "EXEC [db_mod].[sys].[sp_addrolemember] N'db_datawriter', N'my_user'" // via SqlCommand
   bulk.WriteToServer(table);
}
finally
{
   "EXEC [db_mod].[sys].[sp_droprolemember] N'db_datawriter', N'my_user'" // via another SqlCommand
}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> User does not have permission to
>   perform this action.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GRANT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187797.aspx) and [REVOKE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186715.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just grant that user that runs the SqlBulkCopy (which inserts data into just exactly one temporary staging table) full rights on that single table only?

Something like:

```
GRANT ALL ON (temporaryTable) TO my_user
```

That should be sufficient to do the SqlBulkCopy operation.

In order to run the `GRANT` command, the user running that command must have the necessary permission to do so - see SQL Books Online on that topic (`GRANT (Transact-SQL)`).

Marc

Answer (score 1):

MSDN [sp_addrolemember](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) tells you what rights are needed...

- Membership in the db_owner fixed database role.
- Membership in the db_securityadmin fixed database role.
- Membership in the role that owns the role.
- ALTER permission on the role

Practically, you'd need to be in the db_securityadmin role.

However, why not just persist INSERT/UPDATE rights via GRANT? The right to grant yourself rights implies enough privilege to not need any more rights...